# Edit Text Focus

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Footer Ends -->


    <!-- Login Form -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/midheader"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:onClick="layoutClick"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <!-- Email Label -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/stk_location"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/cmbstock"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:textColor="#ff0000"
            android:textSize="50dip" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/RONO"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtRO"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="35dip"
            android:width="@dimen/padding_large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ITEMNO"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtItemNO"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="35dip"
            android:width="@dimen/padding_large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ITEMDESC"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtItemDesc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="35dip"
            android:width="@dimen/padding_large" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/BIN"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtBin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"

            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="35dip"
            android:width="@dimen/padding_large" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/botbtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                android:background="@drawable/bgbutton"
                android:height="60dip"
                android:onClick="onBtnClicked"
                android:text="@string/btnSubmit"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30dip"
                android:width="240dip" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/bgbutton"
                android:height="60dip"
                android:onClick="onBtnResetClicked"
                android:text="@string/btnReset"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="30dip"
                android:width="240dip" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have four edit text. When I input some value in first edit text and if it does not have the focus a condition is checked. Now if the condition is false then the focus should on First Edit Text but it is in Last One.

I want if the condition `strRO.equals("12345")` fails then focus should be on first edit text.
But Currently it in last Edit Text.

Please Healp me.

Answer (score 0):

When condition fails...

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Tried All the answer suggested but Last EditText Not Leaving the focus 
Cursor is visible on two edit Text First and Last But when I type changes happen in last one

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(!strRO.equals("12345")){

    editText1.requestFocus();

    editText4.clearFocus();
}
```

Comment: Tried All the answer suggested but Last EditText Not Leaving the focus

Comment: Cursor is visible on two edit Text First and Last But when I type changes happen in last one.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<LinearLayout android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px" >

    <requestFocus />
</LinearLayout>
```

Or you can use this way also:

```
EditText firsteditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt1);
```

> firsteditText.requestFocus();

Comment: Tried Sir But Nothing Happen On my side Sir

Comment: I have tried this many times and each time it works fine,Make sure that you have properly put this in Java code:EditText firsteditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtRO);     firsteditText.requestFocus();   and also try this line code in first edit text:    android:focusable="true"